# Solr missing records from Batch updates

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solr4, solrcloud

We have a job which indexes same documents into SOLR as Batch update. Some of those documents from the Updates are missing from SOLR. For ex: If we index

```
[01,02,03,04]
```

and query by `id:02`. SOLR doesnt return me anything, while I can get back 
`id:01`, `id:03`, `id:04`

Here is the code:

```
private void updateSolrCollection(List<Item> items) throws Exception {
    addToSolr(items);
    commitToSolr();
} 

private void addToSolr(List<Item> items) throws Exception {
    try {
        server.addBeans(items);
    } catch (SolrServerException | IOException e) {
        // try once more
        logger.error("Error while adding to SOLR: " + e.getStackTrace());
        logger.warn("Retrying ADD: retry Unsuccessful Count: " + retryCount);
        try {
            server.addBeans(items);
        } catch (SolrServerException | IOException ex) {

            if (retryEnabled &&  retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
                logger.warn("Retrying ADD Failed, updating lastModifiedDate: " + ex.getStackTrace());
                updateLastModifiedDate(items);
                retryCount++;
            } else {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
}

private void commitToSolr() throws Exception {
    try {
        server.commit();
    } catch (SolrServerException | IOException e) {
        // try Once More
        logger.error("Error while commiting to SOLR: " + e.getStackTrace());
        logger.warn("Retrying Commit: ");
        try {
            server.commit();
        } catch (SolrServerException | IOException ex) {
                throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Why SOLR isn't indexing these records? Could this be an issue with Zookeeper?

Comment: Does the Solr log say anything? Does the document get indexed if you retry the document by itself? Does anything change if you change the order of the documents? Does the 02-document have the same value in the uniqueKey field as another document (if `id` isn't the uniqueKey field). What is the type of the id field?

Comment: @MatsLindh I dont have anything unusual in the logs. Order of the documents is random. `id` is unique, there are no other Documents with duplicate `id`.

Comment: Well, you _are_ swallowing any exceptions that occur when calling `addBeans`. Could the error occur _before_ the document is sent to Solr? Do you see the `add` for the document on the Solr side in the log (if you make the logging verbose enough)

Comment: @MatsLindh, we do print whatever exceptions get thrown, One thing I am thinking about doing is, to print the `UpdateResponse response = server.addBeans(items);NamedList<Object> objList = response.getResponse();`. and see what status everything comes back with. Not sure how much that will be helpful

Comment: You do not - in your `addToSolr` method you're swallowing any `SolrServerException` or `IOException` quietly. (`try { } catch () {}` without a body on the catch). Checking the status after the add is a good start for debugging further.

Comment: @MatsLindh, We are catching the exceptions. I had removed the code to simplify this code. Adding it now. Sorry about it

Comment: @MatsLindh We have hardcommit on and we commit in batches of 2000, is it possible that hardcommit can be causing this issue? [There will be multiple hard commits 1 after another within few milisec]